# Adding an array of custom components built with Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a simple planning JavaFX 8 program using Scene Builder. My program consists of multiple controllers going from one screen to the other as the user advances the program.

I have created a custom component using SceneBuilder. It is just a strip consisting of a label, 2 sliders, and a checkbox in a GridPane. I have a corresponding controller with just the getters and setters for everything inside.

FXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<fx:root fx:id="pane" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="1495.0" type="GridPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Problem">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="name" text="subProblem" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
      <Slider fx:id="time" min="1.0" value="1.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Slider>
      <Slider fx:id="priority" min="1.0" value="1.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Slider>
      <CheckBox fx:id="continuous" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="no-label-checkbox" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
   </children>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1113.0" minWidth="99.0" prefWidth="350.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="526.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="526.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="526.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="526.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="134.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="134.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="16.0" top="16.0" />
   </padding>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
</fx:root>
```

Controller:

```java
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class Problem {
    
    // fields
    @FXML private Label name = new Label();
    @FXML private Slider time = new Slider();
    @FXML private Slider priority = new Slider();
    @FXML private CheckBox continuous = new CheckBox();
    
    // constructor
    public Problem(String name) {
        super();
        this.name.setText(name);
    }
    
    // getters and setters
    public Label getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(Label name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Slider getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    
    public void setTime(Slider time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    
    public Slider getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
    
    public void setPriority(Slider priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
    
    public CheckBox getContinuous() {
        return continuous;
    }
    
    public void setContinuous(CheckBox continuous) {
        this.continuous = continuous;
    }

    // utility methods
    public int getWeighting() {
        return (int) Math.floor(this.time.getValue() * this.priority.getValue());
    }

}
```

I created an ObservableList of this Problem object in one controller:

```java
private ObservableList<Problem> problemList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

//...

// to the next screen
public void toWeighting(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
    saveProblems();
        
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Weighting.fxml"));
    Parent weightingParent = loader.load();
    Scene weightingScene = new Scene(weightingParent);
        
    // access the breakdown controller
    WeightingController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.initData(saveFile, problemList);
        
    Stage window = (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    window.setScene(weightingScene);
    window.show();
        
    }
```

This all works fine. I now passed an ObservableList of my Problem object to the next controller. My next controller has a VBox in it. I would like to add every element of the ObservableList into the VBox. I looked up ways to do this, but nothing would work.

**This is the problem area:**

```java
@FXML private VBox listBox = new VBox();

public void initData(File saveFile, ObservableList<Problem> problemList) throws IOException {
    this.saveFile = saveFile;

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Problem.fxml"));
    for (Problem p : problemList) {
        loader.setRoot(p);
        listBox.getChildren().add(loader.load());
    }
        
}
```

It gave me this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3760)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3488)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1765)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2497)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:411)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:941)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Workspace/eclipse/Problem%20Planner%20JavaFX/bin/application/Problem.fxml:11

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:932)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$RootElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:1290)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at application.WeightingController.initData(WeightingController.java:27)
    at application.BreakdownController.toWeighting(BreakdownController.java:109)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: application.Problem
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: application.Problem.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    ... 70 more
```

I tried other ways, like extending the Problem class with GridPane, making a getter for the GridPane, but either I get an error or nothing shows up. Please help, thanks!

**EDIT: I have this weird solution for now.**
I added an initialize method and an empty constructor to `Problem`, extended GridPane, and edited the trouble method:

```java
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Problem.fxml"));
        
    for (Problem p : problemList) {
        String problemName = p.getName().getText();
        loader.setController(p);
        loader.setRoot(p);
        listBox.getChildren().add(loader.load());
        p.getName().setText(problemName);
    }
```

Comment: The error says your `Problem` class has no zero-argument constructor. One fix is to define said constructor. The other potential fix, I believe, is to annotate the parameter of the existing constructor with `@javafx.fxml.NamedArg("name")`, and make sure you set that value in the FXML file.

Comment: Another issue is that you set the root of the `FXMLLoader` to an instance of `Problem`. Your `<fx:root>` element has a `type=“GridPane”` attribute, but your `Problem` instance is not an instance of `GridPane`. (I.e. `Problem` is not a subclass of `GridPane`.) There are other issues too: you should never initialise fields that are annotated `@FXML`, for example. It looks like you have some very fundamental misunderstandings about how this works, but it’s difficult to pinpoint exactly the things you’re missing as so much is wrong here.

Comment: Also: you have an existing collection of `Problem` instances, which you’re trying to use as the FXML roots (though that won’t work, as described in my previous comment), but then for each time you load the FXML, you’re trying to create a new `Problem` instance, via the `fx:controller` attribute (which won’t work as described by @slaw: there’s no no-arg constructor for `Problem`). There’s just so much wrong here it’s not really possible to discern how you think this works, so it’s hard to know how to correct your misunderstanding.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the reply, I looked up solutions online and changed my code drastically to what I originally did. I previously just wrote `for (Problem p : problemList){listBox.getChildren().add(p); }` which Problem does extend GridPane. There are no errors but nothing showed up on the screen. Basically, I was trying to add a collection of `Problem` instances onto `listBox`.